# How to run multiple avd in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my first Question in s.o.f
I want run two android virtual device but when i run my first avd and i start to run my second avd the avd manager don't let me to do that.it gives me the message like "AVD Nexus_4_API_7 is already running."

what should i do?
How to run multiple avd in android studio?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have two AVDs running in Android Studio just not two of the **same** devices. When you start a device, it locks it's necessary files. This lock causes and error when you try to start a second instance of the same device. To solve this just create another device via AVD manager and then you should not have a problem running them both at the same time.

[image: Two emulators running at the same time]