# In android studio, failed to start the 2nd AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am following this tutorial: 
[Extend an Android app using the IBM Push for Bluemix cloud service](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-android-push-app/index.html#N1033E)
The problem is really nothing to do with the Bluemix. I need to start 2 AVD emulator in Android studio to test the "push" service. I can start the 1st AVD  and see the application running it correctly. But the second emulator won't start. It is duplicated from the 1st one and it can start on its own if I stop the 1st AVD.

I looked the trace in the LogCat view in the AVD monitor, did not see meaning errors. Is it just my laptop doesn't have enough resources? How can I have 2 emulators to test the app?

Thanks.

Zheng

Comment: This is the verbose output of the LogCat view

Comment: Could you specify the specs of the emulator you created? I suppose your system has not enough resources to start two together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure a different new emulator and run the 2 different AVDs separately.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27865409/2003114) you find an example of 2 AVDs running together.