# Cannot launch AVD in emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, launch, android-virtual-device

When I'm trying to run my application in Android Studio I get this error message:

```
  Cannot launch AVD in emulator. Output: emulator: WARNING: encryption is off Hax is enabled Hax ram_size 0x40000000 HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode. emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error audio: Failed to create voice goldfish_audio_in'
    qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
    audio: Failed to create voiceadc' emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version, skipping check (current version '26.0.0-3833124')
```

Comment: restart the android studio then check

Answer (score 0):

Ok so do you already have an emulator of the same instance started on your computer ? Android Studio gives you the freedom to run multiple emulators at once, but not of the same instances, so if you are already running the Nexus "device" with API 22, you cannot start it again.

Please check the link, if that is the problem:
[How to run multiple avd in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27865262/how-to-run-multiple-avd-in-android-studio)

If not, it might me an error caused by Android Studio itself. Try to clear cache and restart,or restart your computer if the first does not solve your problem. Also, try to create another AVD and try to run that one ( aside from the Nexus Api 22 ).

Comment: ok fixed, now i have this problem: 
"Cannot launch AVD in emulator. 
Output: 
emulator: WARNING: encryption is off 
Hax is enabled 
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode. 
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error audio: Failed to create voice goldfish_audio_in'
qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
audio: Failed to create voiceadc' emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version, skipping check (current version '26.0.0-3833124')"

Comment: Have you tried to change the RAM size of the device created. Check the link. Try to leave it at 1GB or try to create another emulator from scratch and test on that one ?   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109774/unable-to-start-emulator-on-android-studio-2-1)

Comment: yes i try to change the emulator memory. How do i create new emulator from scratch?

Comment: AVD Manager -> Create Virtual Device -> Select Device (ex Nexus 5 ) -> Configure Device ( including RAM ) ... and after you are done, click finish and try to build your app on that emulator    [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLOP--Rxv0c)